# DWG source by Python

Tags: python, autocad, dwg

I want to automize my routine tasks such as changing 1 word in huge AutoCAD *.DWG* file with a lot of text blocks (objects in autocad). So, can I open it by *Python*? And how?

Comment: with open('yourfile.dwg', 'r') as f: this way you have it open for reading, check python.org for more documentation

Comment: @Drako "No results found." after search on python.org "dwg".

Comment: @FlyingTeller no! dwg isn't common file for reading.

Comment: @FlyingTeller blocks of text in dwg, it's an objects, but i don't know what kind of and how to parse it. I now Python, and, ofc, know open() function :)

Comment: Drako is right, that line *will open the file*. But if you need to know how to parse it, you must investigate that on your own. Nobody is going to write a full file format parser for you.

Comment: Looks like `dwg` does not have public specifications, so you will probably not find any freely available library to open it

Comment: @FlyingTeller okey, thank u!

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for comment!

Comment: open it binary and replace - should work fine, but needs testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet here is to convert the file first into something like SVG or .dxf and go from there. It's not easy getting the data from a .dwg file in python.

You can make the conversion to SVG in python too using `subprocess` and a command line convert tool like cad2svg.

Comment: Thanks! I've found info 'bout SVG.
Can u give me the way 'bout working with .dxf for further research, plz?

Comment: Take a look at this convertor - https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/TeighaFileConverter to make the conversion, and within python you could look to the `dxfgrabber` library to handle the file.

Comment: Thank you for help!